# How to display some info when you hover on image using Quasar framework and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I need to toggle the word "show" when hovering on it

```
 <div class="col-3">
   <q-img src="../assets/doctors/doctor-08.jpg">
      <div class="absolute-full text-subtitle2 flex flex-center">
            Show
      </div>
    </q-img>
 </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking a question, try to show how you have attempted the question so users can give better feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in CSS. Advantage of this approach:

1. You don't clutter your template and javascript with unnecessary logic.
2. You can add CSS transition effect.

e.g.

```
 <div class="col-3">
   <q-img src="../assets/doctors/doctor-08.jpg" class="my-img">
      <div class="absolute-full text-subtitle2 flex flex-center my-text">
            Show
      </div>
    </q-img>
 </div>

.my-img .my-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.my-img:hover .my-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mouseover and mouseleave event (in div or q-img tag)

```
<div class="col-3">
   <q-img src="../assets/doctors/doctor-08.jpg" @mouseover="showText = true" @mouseleave="showText = false">
      <div class="absolute-full text-subtitle2 flex flex-center" v-show="showText">
            Show
      </div>
    </q-img>
 </div>
```

And in vue instance

```
data: function () {
    return {
      showText: false
    }
  }
```

Comment: it sounds good, but I thought there is a tip to make this code with the quasar framework itself, anyway, I appreciate that, thank you